# How to Hibernate in Ubuntu 17.10 (NOT SLEEP)

Tags: 17.10, suspend, hibernate

```
pm-hibernate
pm-suspend
sudo systemctl hibernate
sudo systemctl suspend
```

They all act as sleep or logout. 
How to hibernate as in windows 10 ( shut system down and keep data )

Comment: do you have a swap partition? I believe the default for 17.10 is a swap file. Hibernate requires a swap partition

Comment: yes i have swap partition